# Trying to debug in vscode, the watch section of the debbuger doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, assembly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTj1a.png)
hi!
I'm trying to debug a program in assembly in vscode, and not only I can not see the registers at the Variables section, I can't use the watch section because everytime I write $eax or anything like that, it just writes "output:" but doesn't say the value.

If anyone knows what to do I'll be thankful.

I tried to look this up but nothing was helpful.

Comment: Use the registers window instead of watch.

Comment: that is the problem, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Include also the version number of your C/C++ extension, what compiler and debugger you have installed, and their version numbers.